# Align Vertical text in Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I was trying to vertical-align the text inside a tooltip but I cannot.

I'm usign Jquery Tools http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertical align a text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101827/how-to-vertical-align-a-text)

Comment: I tried usign vertical-align property, but it's not working because the tooltip is not inside a container.

Comment: Post some sample code, please.

Comment: The tooptip *IS* the container.

Comment: Here is the code example http://www.liftdesignphoto.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

Based on link you provided I see that the tooltips use the following CSS.

```
<div class="tooltip" style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; left: 465px; display: block; opacity: 1; top: 253px; ">
   Tooltip Text
</div>
```

This blog has a great article on vertically centering content

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Based on that and assuming that you don't have to support IE7 then I would think about the `display: table-cell` method. You would apply this to your tooltip class. You would have to wrap the cell content first though.

```
div.tooltip {display:table;}
div.tooltip > span {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}

//if you can't wrap content in span yourself then use jquery to do it
$('div.tooltip').wrap('<span />');

//the new html
<div class="tooltip" style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; left: 465px; display: block; opacity: 1; top: 253px; ">
   <span>Tooltip Text</span>
</div>
```

Was just thinking that we don't know how css is applied to these tooltips. They are assigned the display property `block`. You may need to make sure that alterations to the tooltip by the plugin code doesn't remove your `display:table` property. So you may actually want to double wrap the content to ensure your css doesn't get overwritten.