# Center text in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm having trouble aligning the text in my navigaiton bar to center (vertically) within its container.

HTML for nav bar:

```
<ul class="navigation">
            <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html" class="navbarlink" >Home</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a href="second.html" class="navbarlink">About</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html" class="navbarlink">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html" class="navbarlink">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS for nav bar:

```
.navigation {
background:#1841c8 url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_background.png);
height:40px;
margin-bottom:0px;
display:block;
}

.navigation .navbar .navbarlink{
color:#FFFFFF;
background:gray;
display:block;
}

.navigation .navbar .navbarlink:hover{
color:#00CCFF;
background: url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png);
text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me which property i'm missing in my CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101827/how-to-vertical-align-a-text

Comment: You probably want to remove that height:40px on .navigation for a start.

Comment: Cthulu I'll check it out. @Billy Moat The 40px on navigation is for my background to fit properly.

Comment: Okay Jonas, I just thought that might be very tight with the amount of links you have. If you could post up a link to your page or make a sjfiddle that would be great.

Comment: @Billy Moat
http://mohrdevelopment.com

Comment: @Torr3nt

Thank you, works like a charm.
Except that it doesnt fit the bar (40px) in height. But i suppose i can deal with that myself :)

Comment: Your background is on the anchor. You can move the background to the li, and you should be fine.

Comment: Or you can add padding if you want a bigger click area on the anchor. If your text size is 12px, you can have padding: 14px 5px; (14 on top and bottom, 5 on the left and right).

Comment: I fixed it quite simply by adding Display:inline-block & Line-height: 40px to the .navigation .navbar .navbarlink{

Anything wrong with this way?

Comment: With the way its laid out, you want the inline-block elements to be the lis, because otherwise, the anchors would be inline-block within the li tag. Try this out. http://jsfiddle.net/aSxp9/3/

Comment: As an aside, you don't seem to be closing any of your EM tags. Also I think you could achieve what you are trying to do with those em tags or the B tags. Use your main backgrouind on the LI elements and swap them on hover of the LI. And place your individual icons as backgrounds to the A tags. Hope that makes sense and helps you tidy up your code a bit. With regard to centering the text I always simply use padding-top with the A tags.

Comment: @torr3nt That works aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `margin-bottom:0` on .navigation and instead putting `margin:50% 0 50% 0;`